# Find the value of $\sin x+\sin 3x+\sin 5x....\sin 29x$

Tags: trigonometry

This was a part of a larger question. I have the solution with me, but I have a problem with the way they wrote it.

The expression was written as 
$$\frac{\sin (\frac{x+29x}{2})\sin(\frac{2x.15}{2})}{\sin\frac{2x}{2}}$$

Is this a formula that I am not aware of, or was it somehow derived from the specific information

Comment: Hint: multiply by $\cos x$ and express $2\sin nx\cos x$ as the difference of two sines. The resulting series telescopes.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note

\begin{align}
&2\sin x\sin x=1 -\cos2x\\
 &2\sin x\sin 3x= \cos 2x - \cos4x\\
 &2\sin x\sin 5x= \cos 4x - \cos6x\\
&\cdots\\
& 2\sin x \sin 29x= \cos 28x -\cos30x
\end{align}

Sum up both sides

$$2\sin x\ ( \sin x+\sin 3x+\sin 5x+....+\sin 29x) = 1-\cos30x$$
to arrive at
$$\sin x+\sin 3x+\sin 5x +\cdots+\sin 29x=\frac{1-\cos30x}{2\sin x}=\frac{\sin^2 15x}{\sin x}$$

Comment: So can it be treated as a formula, or does if need to be derived every time

Comment: @Aditya - It may be unfamiliar to many, which should not be taken as a well-known formula.

Comment: But can it be treated as one, because I don’t really need to show my work to any teacher, so would it apply to every problem?

Comment: @Aditya - It should be okay to assume that your teacher knows about it, unless she/he requires you to derive

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{29}\sin\left(kx\right)=\Im\left[\sum_{k=1}^{29}\left(e^{ikx}\right)\right]$$$$=\Im\left[e^{ix}\frac{e^{i\left(29\right)k}-1}{e^{ix}-1}\right]=\Im\left[e^{ix}\cdot\frac{\left(e^{i\left(\frac{29}{2}\right)x}\right)e^{i\left(\frac{29}{2}\right)x}-e^{-i\left(\frac{29}{2}\right)x}}{e^{i\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)x}\left(e^{i\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)x}-e^{-i\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)x}\right)}\right]$$$$=\Im\left[e^{i\left(15\right)x}\cdot\frac{2i\sin\left(\frac{29}{2}x\right)}{2i\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)}\right]$$$$=\Im\left[(\cos\left(\left(15\right)x\right)+i\sin\left(\left(15\right)x\right))\frac{2i\sin\left(\frac{29}{2}x\right)}{2i\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)}\right]$$$$=\sin\left(\left(15\right)x\right)\frac{\sin\left(\frac{29}{2}x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)}$$

Comment: $\sin x = \Im(e^{ix})$

Answer (score 3):

Note that 
$$\sum_{r=1}^n\sin(a+(r-1)b)=\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{2a+(n-1)b}{2}\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{nb}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\dfrac{b}{2}\right)}$$
To prove, multiply and divide by $2\sin\left(\dfrac{b}{2}\right)$ in LHS, apply the identity $$2\sin x\sin y=\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y)$$
and do the telescopic sum.